# How can I add a '<input type="checkbox" checked>' attribute to all li dynamically created list items using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an accordion from my unordered list items from the demo here: https://codepen.io/abergin/pen/BaKVWd it's really simple and just what I need, however I need to be able to attach a - `<input type="checkbox" checked>` value to all my li elements. I do not have access to the HTML.

The list is displayed inside a bootstrap modal iframe...

```
<div class="modal-body"><iframe id="researchiframe" name="display-frame" style="width:100%;height:600px;"></iframe></div>
```

My list code is below.

```
<ul id="result_details" style="padding:0px">
// li elements are created dynamically here//
</ul>
```

I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: That's no attribute; that's an element. Also, please read [ask], where it notes, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop through all `<li>` elements. Then you could use `append()` to add the HTML you want after each `<li>` tag.

```js
$('ul#result_details li').each(function(index) {
  $(this).append('<input type="checkbox" checked>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="result_details" style="padding:0px">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense, however not working on my site. Would the fact that it is inside a bootstrap modal make a difference?

Comment: You need to ensure that the dynamic `<li>` tags are added to DOM, **before** you run that script.